# How to see generated pdf on localhost webpage in Golang?

Tags: go

I am trying to see my generated pdf on http://localhost:3333/pdf.

I am trying to learn generating pdf using golang. Tying to make the changes in pdf and see live on localhost server ( http://localhost:3333/pdf ).
But I am clueless that how can I show pdf on localhost.

My Code::

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "os"

    "github.com/krazybee/gofpdf"
)

type bufWriter struct {
    buf []byte
}

func getRoot(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Printf("got / request\n")
    io.WriteString(w, "This is my website!\n")
}

func getHello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Printf("got /hello request\n")
    io.WriteString(w, "Hello, HTTP!\n")
}

func generatePDF(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    pw := new(bufWriter)
    pdf := gofpdf.New("P", "mm", "A4", "")
    fontsize := 12.0

    font := "Arial"

    pdf.SetFont("Arial", "", 6)

    pdf.AddPage()
    pdf.SetMargins(5, 5, 5)
    pdf.SetAutoPageBreak(true, 34)

    pdf.SetFont(font, "B", fontsize)

    pdf.MultiCell(0, 8, "TERMS OF LIVING", "", "C", false)
    pdf.MultiCell(0, 8, "Terms", "", "C", false)

    // Show the pdf on localhost web page.
    err = pdf.OutputAndClose(pw)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("PDF served successfully")
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", getRoot)
    http.HandleFunc("/hello", getHello)
    http.HandleFunc("/pdf", generatePDF)

    err := http.ListenAndServe(":3333", nil)
    if errors.Is(err, http.ErrServerClosed) {
        fmt.Printf("server closed\n")
    } else if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error starting server: %s\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}
```

This is what I have tried.
But from the comment `// Show the pdf on the localhost web page.` I don't know how to proceed further after that.

Can someone help me how can I do that? How can I see the generated pdf on a localhost web page?

Comment: You have to set the content-type header and write the PDF to the http.ResponseWriter.

Comment: Can you please give an example code or any reference that I can follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default http package serves the page with Content-type: text/html header. You have to specify the needed header by yourself before writing the page content:

```
w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/pdf")
```

However, the sample code you provided does not work, because a mess with io streams. Here is what you need to change:

```
func generatePDF(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var b bytes.Buffer
    pw := io.Writer(&b)
    pr := io.Reader(&b)
    ...
    err := pdf.Output(pw)
    ...
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/pdf")
    resPDF, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(pr)
    w.Write(resPDF)
    fmt.Println("PDF served successfully")
}
```

I suggest you to have some practice with io library.

Here is the full code that works for me:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "os"

    "github.com/krazybee/gofpdf"
)

func getRoot(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Printf("got / request\n")
    io.WriteString(w, "This is my website!\n")
}

func getHello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Printf("got /hello request\n")
    io.WriteString(w, "Hello, HTTP!\n")
}

func generatePDF(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var b bytes.Buffer
    pw := io.Writer(&b)
    pr := io.Reader(&b)

    pdf := gofpdf.New("P", "mm", "A4", "")
    fontsize := 12.0

    font := "Arial"

    pdf.SetFont("Arial", "", 6)

    pdf.AddPage()
    pdf.SetMargins(5, 5, 5)
    pdf.SetAutoPageBreak(true, 34)

    pdf.SetFont(font, "B", fontsize)

    pdf.MultiCell(0, 8, "TERMS OF LIVING", "", "C", false)
    pdf.MultiCell(0, 8, "Terms", "", "C", false)

    // Show the pdf on localhost web page.
    err := pdf.Output(pw)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/pdf")
    resPDF, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(pr)
    w.Write(resPDF)
    fmt.Println("PDF served successfully")
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", getRoot)
    http.HandleFunc("/hello", getHello)
    http.HandleFunc("/pdf", generatePDF)

    err := http.ListenAndServe(":3333", nil)
    if errors.Is(err, http.ErrServerClosed) {
        fmt.Printf("server closed\n")
    } else if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error starting server: %s\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked, But when I am making changes in pdf and saving the file, It is not reflecting immidiately. I have to restart the server again and again.
Is there any way I can see live changes in pdf?

Comment: @KJ you mean we can not render pdf instantly? There is no such way to do that. We must restart the server after saving the new changes. Is it what you want to say? please confirm.

Comment: "when I am making changes in pdf and saving the file, It is not reflecting immidiately." - I am not sure what you mean here. You generate a pdf, and print it. You can dynamically render a pdf, for example, print a random string in it, and it will be refreshed each time you reload the browser page, without any server restart. I think your question was that when you change the golang code, you have to restart the server, and it is absolutely true.